# Programming and compilation: Chromium vs Firefox

Tags: firefox, compilation, chromium

For educational and "entertainment" purposes which browser between Firefox and Chromium is better to choose for play with its code and then compile it, in your opinion? Which has a better code organization? Which of them is "simplest" to compile? And to debug?

Thank you

Comment: Haven't played around with Firefox's source code but I would still pick Chromium as I have been involved in it for a few years for now. It's not simplest to compile and debug. The multi-process architecture of Chromium makes it difficult to debug and compile times will depend on your computer's horse power.

Comment: @Asesh Thank you a lot, this is really interesting. I hope that someone tells his opinion about Firefox, for comparing compilation e debugging processes